# Andriod Selenium testing by Python - connecting problem

Tags: selenium, python, android

I'm trying to get the Selenium Android client to run in my emulator:

1. Install SDK
2. Run emulator
3. Install android-server-2.0rc1.apk in the emulator and devices
4. Forward the port by adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080
5. Install Python and set the selenium.py seript as this page says: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_installing_python_driver_client.html
6. Run the web driver client in the emulator
7. Run the command in Python `from selenium import webdriver`
8. This gives me the following error message:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
   from selenium import webdriver
   ImportError?: cannot import name webdriver
   ```

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the selenium bindings for Python. Try this:

```
sudo pip install selenium
```

Answer (score 1):

Run python and do this:

```
import sys

sys.path
```

it will return sort of "list of folders/modules" you can import from.
To be able to import from `selenium`, you need to have it in this list,
it appears similar to this:

```
'.../lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.12.1-py2.6.egg',
```

If you don't have one, chances are you did not installed it properly, or it didn't make it to your `pythonpath`.

If you still sure that you did install it, try to add path to the selenium folder to the `sys.path` manually like this:

```
import sys

path_to_selenium = '/path/to/installed/selenium'
sys.path.append(path_to_selenium)

from selenium import webdriver
```

For more information read [this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), [this](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ImportError) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=importerror).